# How to automatically link asset files that I add manually to my project (JS and CSS) to a template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have been using AngularJS for around 6 months now and have recently started using Yeoman and Grunt to help with my workflow.

Is there a way to have grunt update my index.html file for files/scripts that I add manually into my app folder?

I know that if I use the command:

```
$ yo angular:service New-Service
```

then a boilerplate file will be created and my index.html file will be updated to reference the new file.

Is there a way to have this functionality for files that I do not add with the syntax shown above?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching a linker. There are several grunt plugins to do this job :
- [grunt-asset-linker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-asset-linker)
- [grunt-sails-linker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sails-linker)

Here is what you have to do :

1. Add a grunt task with (grunt-contrib-watch) to watch folders where files are added
2. Add a task with (**E.g** : grunt-asset-linker) to link all files from one or many folder to your `index.html`

Comment: sorry haha totally forgot to do that. I can't upvote though im too new :(